# Unity: Shortcut to open new Terminal doesn't work after enabling workspaces

Tags: unity, command-line, shortcuts

Since I enabled workspaces on my Ubuntu System (14, Unity window manager), the `ctrl-alt-T` shortcut to open a new Terminal does not work anymore (in any of the workspaces)? Does anybody know why?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/975416

But you can solve the problem by assigning a new keyboard shortcut to terminal

From Dash open `Keyboard` then go `Shortcuts` tab and navigate to `Custom Shortcuts` then Click on `+`

[image]

Use the following command

```
gnome-terminal --profile=Default
```

Now assign the key combination (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) on clicking on it.